# Is there a way to specify multiple HTML elements inside a CSS class clause?

Tags: html, css

I want to alter multiple HTML elements that live inside a singular CSS class.

For example:

```
<div class="main">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Good Morning</p>
</div>
```

I know it is possible to do this:

```
.main h1 { ... }
.main p {...}
```

Is it possible to create a single CSS clause that does this in one line? (Like this:)

```
.main h1,p {...}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a scoped *universal* selector, as a shortcut for every element inside `.main`, e.g.

```
.main * { ... }
```

or list all the specific elements inside `.main` using `:is` or `:where` (the difference is in their specificity), e.g.

```
.main :where(h1, p) { ... }
```

---

Reference (`MDN`):
— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is
— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where

Comment: Just to add as a suggestion: The first one could be resource intensive. `.main h1, .main p` should be faster and less resource intensive.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan  [The CSS Universal Selector Is Slow And Should Be Avoided” — Yet Another Lie!](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-css-universal-selector-is-slow-and-should-be-avoided-yet-another-lie-eb4d15f4c320) : [...] «_There’s no evidence to support the claim that the universal selector is somehow “bad”_»

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I stand corrected! Thanks for teaching me something very interesting today :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```css
.main h1,
.main p {...}
```